# React JS - npm test failure, withoutRouter must be inside Router

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, react-router, circleci

When running npm test this error occurs, anybody know how to fix it?

```
 FAIL  src/App.test.js (13.306s)
  × renders learn react link (2323ms)
  ● renders learn react link
    Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>
      4 |
      5 | test('renders learn react link', () => {
    > 6 |   const { getByText } = render(<App />);
        |                         ^
      7 |   const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
      8 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
      9 | });
```

I've tried adding BrowserRouter in the app.test.js too, but that did nothing.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
    </BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.register();
```

App.js contains the routing of the website, with a transition effect and a switch which contains the routes.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {GlobalStyle} from "./global.styles";
import Footer from "./components/footer/footer.component";
import {MainContainer} from "./components/common/Container.component";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/nav/nav.component";
import {CSSTransition, TransitionGroup} from "react-transition-group";
import Particles from "react-particles-js";
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import HomePage from "./pages/homepage/homepage.component";
import ProcessPage from "./pages/process/process.component";
import ProcessIndepth from "./pages/process/process-indepth/processIndepth.component";
import ServicePage from "./pages/service/service.component";
import AboutPage from "./pages/about/about.component";
import ContactPage from "./pages/contact/contact.component";
import Cookies from "./pages/cookies/cookies.component";
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            navbarOpen: false,
            showSuccess: true,
        }
    }
    handleNavbar = () => {
        this.setState({
            navbarOpen: !this.state.navbarOpen
        });
    };
    render() {
        const {location} = this.props;
        return (
        <div>
                <div>
                    <MainContainer>
                        <GlobalStyle/>
                        <Navbar
                            navbarState={this.state.navbarOpen}
                            handleNavbar={this.handleNavbar}
                        />
                        <Route render={({location}) => (
                            <TransitionGroup>
                                <CSSTransition
                                    key={location.key}
                                    classNames="fade"
                                    timeout={800}
                                >
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
                                        <Route exact path='/proces' component={ProcessPage} />
                                        <Route exact path='/samarbejdsproces' component={ProcessIndepth} />
                                        <Route exact path='/services' component={ServicePage}/>
                                        <Route exact path='/om_os' component={AboutPage}/>
                                        <Route exact path='/kontakt' component={ContactPage}/>
                                        <Route exact path='/cookies' component={Cookies} />
                                    </Switch>
                                </CSSTransition>
                            </TransitionGroup>
                        )}
                        />
                        {location.pathname !== "/" && <Footer/>}
                    </MainContainer>
                </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';
test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const linkElement = getByText(/learn react/i);
  expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

The purpose of the test is to deploy the website with circleci.

Comment: By wrapping the `<App />` component with a `<BrowserRouter />` in App.test.js you should be able to solve that problem. How exactly did you add BrowserRouter to App.test.js?

Comment: I added the browserouter to App.teat.js by testing <App /> inside it, like the example you gave :)

Comment: Can you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yeah of course my bad :) 

```const { getByText } = render(<BrowerRouter><App /></BrowserRouter);```

Comment: For our projects, we use the [testing-library wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) option. With this option, you can create a custom render function with all providers needed. We have two custom wrapper options; one for components and one for containers (redux).

Answer (score -1):

This is because unable to find an element with the text: /learn react/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements.

So I did it this way:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storeConfig from './store/storeConfig';
import App from './App';

const store = storeConfig();

test('renders without crashing', () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, div);
});
```

Comment: This looks like it has nothing to do with OP's problem, they are not even using react-redux, and the error they are getting happens before the line with the regular expression you mentioned.